# How to replace a value in a row with the previous row based on a condition in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data table:

```
Index Value

0      NaN

1      1.15

2      2.25

3      2.33
```

Condition: First check wherever previous row value is not NaN then replace current row value with previous row value.

Desired output:

```
Index Value

0      NaN

1      1.15

2      1.15

3      1.15
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Compare values for missing values, then get first consecutive value and replace another by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), forward filling missing values and last replace original missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[np.nan,1.15,2.15,3.15,np.nan,2.1,2.2,2.3]})

m = df.notna()
df1 = df.where(m.ne(m.shift())).ffill().where(m)

print (df1)
   Value
0    NaN
1   1.15
2   1.15
3   1.15
4    NaN
5   2.10
6   2.10
7   2.10
```

**Details**:

```
print (m.ne(m.shift()))
  Value
0   True
1   True
2  False
3  False
4   True
5   True
6  False
7  False

print (df.where(m.ne(m.shift())))
 Value
0    NaN
1   1.15
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5   2.10
6    NaN
7    NaN

print (df.where(m.ne(m.shift())).ffill())
   Value
0    NaN
1   1.15
2   1.15
3   1.15
4   1.15
5   2.10
6   2.10
7   2.10
```

Comment: When the `df` is `pd.DataFrame({'Value':[np.nan,1.15,2.15,3.15,np.nan,2.1,2.2,2.3]})` the expected output is `NaN 1.15 1.15 1.15 NaN 2.1 2.1 2.1` but this gives `NaN 1.15 1.15 1.15...` all 1.15

Comment: @jezrael Thanks. Also it would be nice if you can explain it.

Comment: @jezrael Coolest answer. +1 ;)

Comment: @jezrael One more question I have a dataframe pd.Dataframe({"Value:[np.nan,1,5,np.nan,6,-1,5,np.nan,6]}), here to logic should reset after every -1 so desired output expected is NaN  1 .5  1. 5  6  -1  5  5  5